# ASP.NET SqlConnection error: "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

What's wrong this T-SQL query :

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim SQLData As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Name ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", SQLData)
        SQLData.Open()
        If cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar > 0 Then
            Label1.Text = "You have already voted this service"
            Return
        End If
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tabel1 (Name) VALUES('" & Trim(Label1.Text) & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Label1.Text = "Thank You !"
        SQLData.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Showing an erro message in Con.open

The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: What's wrong? You are not parameterizing either one.

Comment: ya i wanna run two queries in single button clixk ..if record found then show mag in label else ...insert record ...

Comment: SQL Injection Heaven! And your answer is in your error message: `con` has no connection string.

Comment: Can any body re-edit this code ....i m beginner in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend an approach something like this:

```
Protected Function Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    ' define and create your one single SqlConnection and protect it by using a "using()....." block
    Using _connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        ' define and craete your SqlCommand to count your occurences and make it a proper, parametrized query
        Using cmdSelect As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Name = @Name", _connection)
            ' add the parameter to your SqlCommand, define the datatype and length
            cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)

            ' set the value for that parameter
            cmdSelect.Parameters("@Name").Value = TextBox1.Text.Trim()

            ' open connection, execute query, set return value
            _connection.Open()
            If cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar() > 0 Then
                            Label1.Text = "You have already voted this service"
                Return 
            End If
        End Using

        ' define second query to insert data reusing the existing connection
        Using cmdInsert As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(Name) VALUES(@Name)", _connection)
            ' add the parameter to your SqlCommand, define the datatype and length
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)

            ' set the value for that parameter
            cmdInsert.Parameters("@Name").Value = Label1.Text.Trim()

            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        _connection.Close()
    End Using

    Label1.Text = "Thank You !"
End Function
```

Points to consider:

- you have **one** `SqlConnection` - that's good enough for both queries, reuse it!
- **always** put your disposable objects like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` into `Using.....` blocks to protect them and make sure they get properly disposed
- **always** use **parametrized queries** - do **NOT** under any circumstances just concatenate together your SQL statements - that's a big huge gaping security hole, inviting SQL injection attacks - just **DON'T** do it - EVER!
- if I could, I would try to separate your UI elements from the code - try to put this code into a separate method that will take in the string values from the caller, and will return a result string to be set on the UI (`Label1.Text=`). Mixing code that queries the database and setting the UI at the same time is messy and leads to spaghetti code - try to separate those things
- put your connection string into the `web.config` into the `<connectionStrings>` section and read it from there - don't have your connection string as a string literal all throughout your code!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are opening a connection (`SQLData`), ignoring it, then trying to open a new connection (`con`) without giving it a connection string. Instead of this:

```
     Dim con As New SqlConnection
     Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
     con.Open()
     cmd.Connection = con
```

you should have:

```
     Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
     cmd.Connection = SQLData
```

Also, it is very bad practice to insert string value inline in SQL as you have.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things I see wrong there. First, (other than the SQL injection vulnerability) is that you typed `Table1` once, and `Tabel1` the other time. While that could be what you want, I doubt it. Next you're creating a second connection. That doesn't seem to be needed. Use the existing `SQLData` object instead of `con`. You can also reduce the lines starting from the declaration of `cmd` (inclusive) to the `ExecuteNonQuery` call (exclusive) with this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Tabel1 (Name) VALUES('" & Trim(Label1.Text) & "')", SQLData)
```

Now back to that SQL injection vulnerability. What if someone's name is "James O'Brian" (or something else with an apostrophe in it)?